# logic behind Negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem

Is reaching 30th failure before 3rd success equivalent to reaching 0,1 or 2 successes before 30th failure?

that is if Y counts number of successes before k-th failure and
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\begin{pmatrix} y+k-1\\ y \end{pmatrix} (1-p)^k p^y
\end{equation}
then is it correct that probability of reaching 30th failure before 3rd sucess is equal to 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^2\mathbb{P}(Y=i)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If we set $k = 30$, then $\mathbb P(Y = 0) + \mathbb P(Y = 1) + \mathbb P(Y = 2)$ is the probability of reaching 30 failures before 3 successes.

Comment: but about if we set $X$ to count failures till $k$th success, that is
$
\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\begin{pmatrix) x+k-1\\ x\end{pmatrix}(1-p)^xp^r$
then isn't right that $\mathbb{P}(X=30)$ with $r=3$ would be probability of reaching 30th failure before 3 success, which would equivalent to probability that machine will shut down before 3 successes?